# Want to resize a image with better resolution in swift

Tags: swift, imageview, resize, cloudinary

I have a image which is uploaded in the image cloud-cloudinary using the API.The response of the upload gives me the cloudinary uploaded url.
Example of one image is as given:[image]

This image is of 120*67 which is uploaded.Now in my app,it looks like this.
[image]

The width of my image is as per the phone screen width and the height is fixed to 324.Now i want to resize this 120*67 image to the width and height of my image in the app without losing its clarity.I have made the content mode as scale to fill for the imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, scaling up (non vectorized) images without compromising their quality is not possible (without machine learning). Some software programs have complex algorithms to help with upscaling, but that's also to a limited extent.

You should upload a larger version of your image to Cloudinary, and request it downscaled to the desired resolution.
You should also check out [responsive layout design](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/responsive_images).

If the image is vectorized (e.g - SVG), you need to make sure you're not requesting a rasterized version of it. I.E -

`https://res.cloudinary.com/<cloud name>/image/upload/fl_sanitize/<image name>.svg`

will keep the image vectorized.

Comment: What is non vectorized image?We cant control the type of image the user uploads?So how it be can shown properly from our end then?

Comment: Non vectorized (aka rasterized) images are defined with pixels, whereas vectorized images are defined with "points on a Cartesian plane" - you can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics).

How do your users upload images? If you're using Cloudinary's upload widget, you can define restrictions rules on the uploaded images like `minImageWidth` and `minImageHeight` - https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget#upload_widget_options